# Why is NetworkManager attempting to control an interface script that doesn't exist?

Tags: networking, centos, networkmanager

I'm showing hundreds of frequently repeated entries in /var/log/messages that don't make sense.  More below the example.

Here's an example, which is repeated ad nauseam in the log file:

```
Oct 15 15:14:01 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Oct 15 15:14:01 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Oct 15 15:14:01 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Oct 15 15:14:01 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Oct 15 15:14:01 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Oct 15 15:14:01 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> (em2): device state change: 4 -> 5 (reason 0)
Oct 15 15:14:01 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Oct 15 15:14:01 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Oct 15 15:14:01 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Oct 15 15:14:01 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Oct 15 15:14:46 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Oct 15 15:14:46 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Timeout) started...
Oct 15 15:14:46 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) scheduled...
Oct 15 15:14:46 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Timeout) complete.
Oct 15 15:14:46 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) started...
Oct 15 15:14:46 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) failed (no IP configuration found)
Oct 15 15:14:46 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> (em2): device state change: 7 -> 9 (reason 5)
Oct 15 15:14:46 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <warn> Activation (em2) failed.
Oct 15 15:14:46 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> Activation (em2) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) complete.
Oct 15 15:14:46 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> (em2): device state change: 9 -> 3 (reason 0)
Oct 15 15:14:46 mybox NetworkManager[2570]: <info> (em2): deactivating device (reason: 0).
```

I originally had two interfaces on this machine, but am now only using one (em1).  The second interface (em2) no longer exists in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`

The networking service has been restarted, and the machine itself.  Still  getting references to `em2`.

I've looked in /etc for hidden config entries with

```
find /etc/ -exec grep -Hn em2 {} \;
```

But nothing comes up for "em2" (aside from garbage text in sha/md5 strings)

Couple questions:

1) Where else would `NetworkManager` be pulling config data from?  Or is NM seeing a physical card and trying to bring it up even though a network interface script doesn't exist?

2) Is `NetworkManager` absolutely required for managing network interfaces?  This machine uses a min install of `CentOS 6`.  I think NM was installed early on but I later used vim to hand configure the network scripts.

The primary interface (em1) works fine.

Comment: *"Is NetworkManager absolutely required for managing network interfaces?"* -> No.  You can disable it and set stuff up yourself if you want.

Comment: @goldilocks add your comment as a question so I can up your rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is NetworkManager absolutely required for managing network interfaces?"

No. You can disable it and set stuff up yourself if you want. I've been doing this for years on personal systems since there's barely any "network managing" to do anyway, and I find NM a little irritating.

You do have to learn how to use stuff like `ifconfig`/`ip`, `dhclient`/`dhcpcd`, `wpa_supplicant`, etc.  The only issue I've ever had is automating wifi to reconnect when necessary.  That got solved with a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

. $UTIL_SRC_DIR/util-func.sh
checkForSame

. /etc/wifi.conf

exec 1> /dev/null
exec 2>> $log
echo $(date) > $log
# without check_interval set, we risk a 0 sleep = busy loop
if [ ! "$check_interval" ]; then
    echo "No check interval set!" >> $log
    exit 1
fi

startWifi () {
    dhclient -v -r
    killall dhclient
    iwconfig $wlan essid $essid
    dhclient -v $wlan
}

ifconfig $eth down
ifconfig $wlan up
startWifi

while [ 1 ]; do
    ping -c 1 $router_ip & wait $!
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        echo -e "\n$(date) attempting restart..." >> $log
        startWifi
        sleep 1
    else sleep $check_interval
    fi
done
```

The `checkForSame()` thing just ensures this isn't running already.  I live out in the country and don't use wifi encryption at home, so `startWifi()` is pretty simple. My main point here is the logic (pinging the router and killing previous dhclients before restart), and I can report this works like a charm: it does report the occasional reconnect in the log, but I never notice any interruptions (disconnects seem to occur when the interface is idle).

Comment: Quick followup. Once I remove NM, will the ONBOOT option still be recognized when the system boots?

Comment: Yes. `/etc/sysconfig` is actually fedora/redhat/centos specific. The `network-scripts` stuff is used by the networking service, I believe.  But without NM that won't connect you to a network, it just configures the interfaces.